# Trying to prove $\{[−\infty, a)\}_{a\in\mathbb{R}}$ generates The borel sigma algebra of the extended reals. Any hints?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-sets

I have already proved several similar questions but for the Borel sigma algebra on the reals and I am now a bit stuck when working with the extended reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking complements, we see each $[a,\infty]$ is obtained. Since $(a,\infty]=\cup [a+1/n,\infty],$ we obtain each $(a,\infty].$ Given reals $a<b,$ we obtain $(a,\infty]\cap [-\infty,b) =(a,b).$ That's a good start ...

Comment: Thanks, so we can now say that the sigma algebra generated by these sets contains the Borel sigma algebra of the reals. As the open intervals $(a,b)$ generate this.                                          How would we conclude the proof?